# How can we prevent the spent time to lost?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just viewed an answer (which was posted only a minute ago). I was just like amazed about the person who posted answer because it has 4 `Up-Votes`, and he really deserved because it was a quality answer (Detail, reference, an example).

Here is screen when I open that question,

[image]

As I said I was amazed on very quick action (4 Up-Votes just in a minute), so I wanted to see the user profile (who posted answer) and reputation.

[image]

But when I came back to the [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261972/trying-to-remove-an-element-from-array-from-user-input), it was deleted.

[image]

My concern is why people don't value to experts people time. You can see the answer, it has enough detail to understanding, up-votes for recommendation from other experts and an example for prove.

For me it is so careless activity if someone wasting experts time, because behind the posted answer there is lot of researched and handwork.

I am just thinking if SO team can record the activity or something so in this way there will be a barrier which can be prevent the spent time to lost. Kindly forgive me for poor grammar. I am so sorry if it an off topic.

Comment: I just have to say that a lot of people coming to SO and potentially voting are not experts.

Answer (score 16):

We can avoid time being wasted by voting to close duplicate questions instead of answering them. [The question you're referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261972/trying-to-remove-an-element-from-array-from-user-input) was closed within minutes of being asked by a gold-badge user. It was closed as a duplicate of a question that's been viewed millions of times, and upvoted thousands of times. It's not an obscure question, and the new question didn't really add anything unique, so I think it's fine to delete it.

Comment: ...and now there's this double-edged sword of the fact that the question was deleted with an upvoted answer, thus sharply penalizing the OP.

Comment: @Makoto the answer was self deleted - presumably because they realised that their answer just duplicated the information in the answers on the duplicate target.

Comment: Okay - now I follow you @ChrisF.

Answer (score 15):

The timeline of the question was as follows:

1. It's asked.
2. The answer is posted.
3. The question gets closed as a duplicate (of a near canonical question).
4. The answerer realises that their answer adds little or no value and deletes it.
5. The OP realises that their question isn't needed and deletes it - which they can because it hasn't got any upvoted answers any more.

If you try to ask the same question, the first thing you get when entering the title is this popup:

[image]

However, the duplicate isn't immediately visible in the list of "questions that may already have your answer". Also on entering the body and tags doesn't change that list, so I can see why the OP might have persisted in asking.

If the search was redone after the tags were entered then I'm sure the duplicate would have been found. In that case the OP should have followed the advice in the popup and searched again - either on the site directly or via Google.

Answer (score -1):

Building a little on [what Bill said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373921/50049):

> We can avoid time being wasted by voting to close duplicate questions instead of answering them.

95% of the time, that's exactly right. Answering *exact* duplicates can lead to time being wasted by:

- Time spent on answers totally wasted because they say essentially the *same* exact thing as those on the duplicate
- Time spent "pruning" merge candidates is compounded needlessly (when moderators merge two questions and have to clean up answers so they all match the remaining question). No. Moderator. Likes. Doing. This.

We need to better incentivize this in a way that doesn't encourage indiscriminate closing.

But, time is *also* wasted when we lose answers to *strongly related* (or near-duplicate) questions. These are questions where the target, if read and fully understood, would give the OP the knowledge needed to answer their own question. For those, sometimes the best way to say "this is a duplicate" is *with* an answer pointing out how the proposed dup actually applies to the question at hand. The question should still be marked as a duplicate, but since it's not *exact*, an answer or two pointing out how to apply the given info really helps. This also gives a chance to ease animosity folks feel if they feel strongly that their question isn't a duplicate - showing that you actually understand what they want to do goes a long way.

We need to support that better, IMHO. We kinda got started but never got back to it, it's on my list to tackle before the end of the year.

***But, in all honesty, wasted time will always be an ancillary cost to participating on a site like this.***

Well, I guess it depends on how you define wasted. I've put 30 - 45 minutes into answers that I ultimately never posted because someone posted something a lot better than what I was about to contribute, and there wasn't any *need* for my answer. It didn't feel great, but quite honestly, I grew a lot that way.

There's also times I can recall spending a good 30 minutes looking for a duplicate target, only to have someone find a better one .. the opportunities to 'misplace' substantial blocks of time in 10 - 15 minute increments are certainly abundant, but that's almost *everywhere* you can get to on the Internet.

All said and done, my 'wasted' time here has actually been more productive than most daydreaming or puttering around meme generators I've ever done, so again - really depends on what you mean by wasted.

We should (as you note) put more guards in place to prevent this where possible, it's just a little tricky to put guards that are designed to get in people's way in place without getting in people's way :P

Comment: You're director of community strategy... You _can't_ waste time on the site. It's always "researching end-user experience".

Comment: The main issue is that it's easier to answer a duplicate question than to find a decent duplicate target. And the only reward for finding a duplicate is the feeling you made the site cleaner, while answer may be rewarded by some reputation. Are there any plans to address this misfeature?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec [unlikely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#comment1030131_314348): "There is no doubt we've stopped making changes for core users..."